# Webpack: reference bundled components from outside bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a class inside my bundled app that I want to allow users of the app to extend.

Here's what the definition of the bundled class looks like:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class VizPlugin {

    constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    build() {
    }

...

}

export default VizPlugin;
```

The application is a full client/server nodejs app, installed on a customers server. After the app is bundled/deployed/installed on the server, I want the customer to be able to extend the app and add their own custom modules as extensions/plugins, like this:

```
import VizPlugin from './js/viz-plugin'; //there is no viz-plugin.js because it's bundled

class ScatterPlot extends VizPlugin {

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }

    build() {

        //I'd like to also use the reference to d3 from VizPlugin here

    }
...
}

export default ScatterPlot;
```

They would put their javascript code in a directory along side the other bundled client javascript and import from that. Basically, there needs to be a named file called "viz-plugin.js" that can be imported from "scatter-plot.js".

Comment: Did you mean `import VizPlugin from './viz-plugin;`, because something like this `import VizPlugin from 'viz-plugin;` is a path alias import. You could do it with webpack during development or using symlinks and npm if it's already bundled. In any case, you could just export your VizPlugin in your entry point, `export { VizPlugin };`.

Comment: @eMontielG yes, I edited the question so import is './js/viz-plugin' and also to show the export at the end. It's already bundled and there's no 'js/viz-plugin.js' file because it's bundled into a file called "19.js", which webpack decided to call it. I suppose the question is: how can I get webpack to name it viz-plugin.js instead of 19.js?

Comment: I think you need to write more about how the users of the app will write code and plugins for it. Is your app a library? a module? How the users save/update and load their code? How the code that users write will be executed?

Comment: Are you creating a module that will be installed from npm?

Answer (score 2):

Add d3 to your class, and give the extender some way of using it:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class VizPlugin {

    constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.d3 = d3;
    }
    useD3 (callback) {
      callback(this, this.d3);
    }
    build() {
    }

...

}

module.exports = VizPlugin as VizPlugin;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the webpack `SplitChunksPlugin` and give names to individual modules by using [`splitChunks.name`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname).

The following code will look for the `viz-plugin.js` module and tell it to keep it's name:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        name(module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
            const moduleId = module.identifier();
            if( moduleId && moduleId.indexOf('viz-plugin.js') >= 0 ) {
                return 'viz-plugin'
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
},
```

Now, in the dist/build output, there will be a file called "viz-plugin.js" that you can extend, as such:

```
import VizPlugin from './dist/js/viz-plugin';

class ScatterPlot extends VizPlugin {

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }

    build() {

        //I'd like to also use the reference to d3 from VizPlugin here

    }
...
}

export default ScatterPlot;
```